# @DefaultRequestValues replacement in pact jUnit5

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I am trying to migrate my pact consumer tests from jUnit4 to jUnit5.
I've run across a problem with `@DefaultRequestValues` annotation, which is missing in [pact-jvm-consumer-junit5](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/consumer/junit5).

In jUnit4 I was using it as follows:

```scala
@DefaultRequestValues
def defaultRequestValues(request: PactDslRequestWithoutPath): Unit = {
  request
    .method("POST")
    .headers(
      HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType,
      HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, s"$TokenType $ValidToken",
    )
}
```

What is the recommended equivalent in pact-jvm-consumer-junit5?

Answer (score 0):

I used following code:

```scala
def setDefaultRequestValues(builder: PactDslWithProvider): Unit = {
  val defaults = builder.uponReceiving("defaults")
  defaultRequestValues(defaults)
  builder.setDefaultRequestValues(defaults)
}

def defaultRequestValues(request: PactDslRequestWithoutPath): Unit = {
  request
    .method("POST")
    .headers(
      HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType,
      HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, s"$TokenType $ValidToken",
    )
}
```

I call `setDefaultRequestValues` as a first statement of each `@Pact` annotated method.

I arrived at this solution by looking at jUnit4 implelentation in [BaseProviderRule](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/blob/7c41fc10492e15e3886c8d1cfd7dbcc582f95cc5/consumer/junit/src/main/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/junit/BaseProviderRule.java#L214)

```java
protected Map<String, BasePact> getPacts(String fragment) {
  if (pacts == null) {
    pacts = new HashMap<>();
    for (Method m: target.getClass().getMethods()) {
      if (JUnitTestSupport.conformsToSignature(m, config.getPactVersion()) && methodMatchesFragment(m, fragment)) {
        Pact pactAnnotation = m.getAnnotation(Pact.class);
        String provider = ep.parseExpression(pactAnnotation.provider(), DataType.RAW).toString();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(provider) || this.provider.equals(provider)) {
          PactDslWithProvider dslBuilder = ConsumerPactBuilder.consumer(
              ep.parseExpression(pactAnnotation.consumer(), DataType.RAW).toString())
            .pactSpecVersion(config.getPactVersion())
            .hasPactWith(this.provider);
          updateAnyDefaultValues(dslBuilder);
          try {
            BasePact pact = (BasePact) m.invoke(target, dslBuilder);
            pacts.put(this.provider, pact);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Failed to invoke pact method", e);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return pacts;
}

private void updateAnyDefaultValues(PactDslWithProvider dslBuilder) {
  for (Method m: target.getClass().getMethods()) {
    if (m.isAnnotationPresent(DefaultRequestValues.class)) {
      setupDefaultRequestValues(dslBuilder, m);
    } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(DefaultResponseValues.class)) {
      setupDefaultResponseValues(dslBuilder, m);
    }
  }
}

private void setupDefaultRequestValues(PactDslWithProvider dslBuilder, Method m) {
  if (m.getParameterTypes().length == 1
    && m.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(PactDslRequestWithoutPath.class)) {
    PactDslRequestWithoutPath defaults = dslBuilder.uponReceiving("defaults");
    try {
      m.invoke(target, defaults);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException| InvocationTargetException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to invoke default request method", e);
    }
    dslBuilder.setDefaultRequestValues(defaults);
  } else {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method " + m.getName() +
      " does not conform required method signature 'public void " + m.getName() +
      "(PactDslRequestWithoutPath defaultRequest)'");
  }
}
```